# C++ Warning C4244 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++

New to C++, following a tutorial and trying to expand on it. My program compiles but I am getting the error "warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data" on line 23:
`end: return(n1);` when compiling which means my calculator results are incorrect, ignoring decimal places and treating everything as an integer. I cannot find any instance in my code of an int apart from the 1 which I have specifically used. No doubles should be converting at all. Can anyone please have a look and let me know where I've gone wrong? I've attempted turning my current int into a double, and also using various other formatting styles to no avail.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int getNumber(int16_t x)
{
    double n1{};

    if (x == 1)
    {
        cout << "First number: ";
        cin >> n1;
        goto end;
    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        cout << "Second number: ";
        cin >> n1;
        goto end;
    }
        end: return(n1);
}

int getOperator()
{
    char op{};
    cout << "Operator (+, -, *, /): ";
    cin >> op;

    return(op);
}

void printAnswer(double n1, char op, double n2)
{
    if (op == '+')
        cout << n1 << " + " << n2 << " = " << (n1 + n2) << '\n';
    else if (op == '-')
        cout << n1 << " - " << n2 << " = " << (n1 - n2) << '\n';
    else if (op == '*')
        cout << n1 << " * " << n2 << " = " << (n1 * n2) << '\n';
    else if (op == '/')
        cout << n1 << " / " << n2 << " = " << (n1 / n2) << '\n';    
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter two numbers and an operator to perform a calculation." << endl;

    double n1(getNumber(1));
    char op(getOperator());
    double n2(getNumber(2));

    printAnswer(n1, op, n2);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your `getNumber` function returns an `int`, but you're giving it a `double`. What happens when you assign a `double` to an `int`? You get possible loss of data. If you assign `45.23` to an `int`, you will only get `45`. `0.23` will be lost. Also, the `goto` is completely unneeded.

Comment: what's the point of `goto`s here when it always goes there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message is pretty clear. In the function you have defined to get your numbers the return type is `int`

```
    int getNumber(int16_t x)
 // ^^^
```

while you actually pass a `double` type to the return statement.

To get rid of the warning fix the function return type:

```
    double getNumber(int16_t x)
 // ^^^^^^
```

---

As a side note: Please don't use `goto`, especially not if it's completely superfluous. All of your code paths directly lead to label `end:` anyways.